# Gem install requires Build tools when installing cucumber on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, cucumber

I've installed ruby 2 and the ruby.devkit 4.5.2 using chocolatey nuget on Windows 8.1.

I have installed the devkit and run `ruby dk.rb init` and `ruby dk.rb install`

I'm trying to gem install cucumber (either with a gemfile/bundle or at the command line directly) and getting the error message "The 'gherkin' native gem requires installed build tools."

> C:> ruby --version ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32]
>
> C:> gem
>   list gherkin -r
>
> *** REMOTE GEMS ***
>
> aslakhellesoy-gherkin (1.2.3) benhamill-gherkin (2.3.5) bryanl-gherkin
>   (2.11.1.1 ruby java) gherkin (2.12.2 ruby java x86-mingw32
>   x86-mswin32, 2.6.5 universal-dotnet, 2.2.4 i386-mingw32 i386-mswin32,
>   1.0.1 univer sal-java-1.5) gherkin-ruby (0.3.2) gherkin_generator (1.0.4) gherkin_jruby (0.3.1) rspec-gherkin (0.1.2)
>
> C:> gem install
>   gherkin ERROR:  Error installing gherkin:
>           The 'gherkin' native gem requires installed build tools.
>
> Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
>   from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
>   at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

Confusingly if I type `bundle show cucumber` I receive the error:

> Could not find gem 'cucumber'. Did you mean cucumber

one thing I notice here is that the ruby version says x64-mingw32 and the gherkin gem lists instead x86-mingw32.

Is this the issue? Or is there another way I can get this setup working?

Comment: same problem but with android testing. after i do dk.rb install if I run gem install calabash-android I see that it installs the gherkin.